# Understanding fs.writeFileSync(path, data[, options]) Node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have a function that writes data to a file then uploads that file to cloud storage. The file isn't finished writing before it starts uploading so I am getting a partial file in cloud storage. I found that `fs.writeFileSync(path, data[, options])` could help, but I am not exactly sure how it works.

It is my understanding that node runs asynchronously and I have several async processes running prior to this portion of code. I understand what synchronous vs asynchronous means, but I am having a little trouble understanding how it plays in this example. Here are my questions if I replace the below code with `fs.writeFileSync(path, data[, options])`

1. What do the docs mean by *"Synchronously append data to a file"*

   - a. Will the next lines of code be halted until the `fs.writeFileSync(path, data)` is finished?
   - b. Are previous asynchronous processes halted by this line of code?
2. If other async processes are not affected how is `writeFileSync` different the `writeFile`?
3. Is there a callback feature in `writeFileSync` that I am misunderstanding?

Code for reference

```
outCsv = "x","y","z"
filename = "file.csv"
fs.writeFile(filename, outCsv, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('The file was saved!');
        bucket.upload(filename, (err, file) => {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            console.log('The file was uploaded!');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, jonrsharpe for the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will the next lines of code be halted until the fs.writeFileSync(path, data) is finished?

Yes. It is a blocking operation. Note that you're assuming that `fs.writeFileSync` *does* finish.

> Are previous asynchronous processes halted by this line of code?

Kinda. Since JavaScript is single-threaded, they will also not be running while the file is writing but will queue up at the next tick of the event loop.

> If other async processes are not affected how is writeFileSync different the writeFile?

It blocks any code that comes after it. For an easier example consider the following:

```
setTimeout(() => console.log('3'), 5);
console.log('1'); // fs.writeFileSync
console.log('2');
```

vs

```
setTimeout(() => console.log('3'), 5);
setTimeout(() => console.log('1'), 0); // fs.writeFile
console.log('2');
```

The first will print 1 2 3 because the call to `console.log` blocks what comes after. The second will print 2 1 3 because the setTimeout is non-blocking. The code that prints 3 isn't affected either way: 3 will always come last.

> Is there a callback feature in writeFileSync that I am misunderstanding?

Don't know. You didn't post enough code for us to say.

This all begs the question of why to prefer `fs.writeFile` over the alternative. The answer is this:

The sync version *blocks*.

While it's taking however long it takes your e.g. webserver isn't handling requests.

Comment: Thank you so much this was very helpful!